# using ../ at go:embed annotation

Tags: go, embedded-resource

I want to embed a file placed one level above the golang file code.
for example:

dir1

- file.go

dir2

- file.txt

How to embed file.txt inside file.go using go:embed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) states:

> Patterns may not contain ‘.’ or ‘..’ or empty path elements, nor may they begin or end with a slash.

So what you are trying to do is not supported directly. Further information is available in the comments on [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46056).

One thing you can do is to put a go file in `dir2`, embed `file.txt` in that and then import/use that in `dir1/file.go` (assuming the folders are in the same package).

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported in the embed package as stated by @Brits (https://pkg.go.dev/embed)

A pattern I like to use is to create an resources.go file in my project's `internal` package and put all my embedded resources in there eg:

```sh
├── cmd\ 
│   └── cool.go
└── internal\
    └── resources\
        ├── resources.go
        ├── fonts\
        │   └── coolfont.ttf
        └── icons\
            └── coolicon.ico
```

resources.go

```golang
import _ "embed"

//go:embed fonts/coolfont.fs
var fonts byte[] // embed single file

//go:embed icons/*
var icons embed.FS // embed whole directory
```

There are libraries that can help with this as well such as those listed here https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#resource-embedding

But I've not run into a use case where plain old embed wasn't enough for my needs.

Comment: how to embed from subfolder? like //go:embed fontDir/fonts.ttf

Comment: Hi! To embed a file directly from subfolder you can do 

`//go:embed fonts/coolfont.ttf` and set the variable type to byte array eg: `var coolfont byte[]`

I've updated the answer with that example too.